# How to pass Base64 image string from Flask Python code to HTML?

Tags: python, html, flask, base64

I have a Flask server and I want to render a base64 image in HTML page.

Flask Code:

```
new_image_string = base64.b64encode(buff.getvalue()).decode("utf-8")
return render_template('perspective_result.html', img_data=new_image_string)
```

HTML CODE:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,+img_data" alt="img_data"  id="imgslot"/>
```

I am getting the below error from browser console:

```
GET data:image/jpeg;base64,+img_data 0 ()
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Please read http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#rendering-templates carefully. First img_data is inside the string and you are not using template syntax.

Comment: See the comment I added to my answer on your prior question about this.

Comment: If you want to pass a variable to a template you need to put it between curly brackets. Do you have something like {{ img_data }} in your template?

Answer (score 8):

`<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{ img_data }}" alt="img_data"  id="imgslot"/>`

This is the way we can solve this.

Comment: This answer is underated. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

1.*First Add A empty Image Tag Without A Source*

2.*Then With Javascript preprocess the base64 data string*

3.*update the Image src with updated base64 data*

```
<img src="" id="img" alt="Chart" height="100" width="100">

<script>
    data = "{{data}}"
    data = data.replace("b&#39;", "") //to get rid of start curly brace code 
    data = data.replace("&#39;", "")  //to get rid of end curly bracecode 

    document.getElementById("img").src = "data:image/png;base64,"+data; // set src
</script>
```