# Display a picture from my sqlite3 database on my python flask web app

Tags: python, html, sqlite, flask

Objective: To make a web app linked to a database where users of the web app can search the database using a name. The image for the respective name should be displayed as a result.

How the database is organised:
The BLOBs are png images.

| Name | Image |
| --- | --- |
| Ann | BLOB |
| Betty | BLOB |

If the user searches for the name " Ann ", Ann's image should be displayed.

I have no clue how to display the picture from the database and would really appreciate some help.

This is the app.py code I have so far.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, make_response,send_file
import sqlite3
app = Flask(__name__)
def Image(search):
    #selection of image from the images table
    conn3 = sqlite3.connect('<path to table>')
    conn3.row_factory  =  sqlite3.Row
    cursor3 = conn3.cursor()
    cursor3.execute("SELECT * FROM Images WHERE Name = ?",
    ("%"+search+"%",) )
    results3 = cursor3.fetchall()
    conn3.close

# content and code for the display page
@app.route('/display', methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def display():
    if request.method  ==  "POST":
        data  =  dict(request.form)
        image  =  Image(data["search"])
    else:
        image = []
    return render_template('display.html', image = image)
```

This is the display.html code that's in the template folder.

```
<!--- PAGE SCALING STATEMENTS - REQUIRED --->

<meta charset="utf-8">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!--- SEARCH BAR FORMATING --->

<form method="post">

  <label for="search"> Case Sensitive Search Bar</label>

  <br>

  <input type="text" name="search" required>

  <input type="submit" value="Search">

  <br>

  <br>


{% if image | length != 0 %}

<img src="{{ image }}" alt="image">

{% else %}

<div id="picture"> No image found</div>

{% endif %}
```

I am just starting out with coding, and this is one of my first projects. Any help/ advice is much appreciated!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Few issues in your code:

1. Cases are not followed correctly. Image is a method I assume.
2. Image method is not returning the result

Your revised code of Image (getImage or get_image) method will be

```
def Image(search):
    #selection of image from the images table
    conn3 = sqlite3.connect('<path to table>')
    conn3.row_factory  =  sqlite3.Row
    cursor3 = conn3.cursor()
    cursor3.execute("SELECT * FROM Images WHERE Name = ?",
    ("%"+search+"%",) )
    row = curose.fetchone()
    conn3.close()
    if row is not None:
        return row[0] --- This is hopefully your image bytes.
    else:
        return None
```

Over here we are assuming your Image field in DB is holding binary data. This needs to convert to base64 equivalent using the method below:

```
encoded_image = base64.b64encode(image_data).decode("utf-8")
```

Now this encoded_image can be passed to your render function.

```
return render_template('display.html', encoded_image = encoded_image)
```

At last, this base54encoded String can be viewed from front end using the html below:

```
 <img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ image_data }}" alt="image">
```

Of course, this will make your code work but you need to take care of validation, null checks, etc.

Same use case if nicely explained here:

[How to pass Base64 image string from Flask Python code to HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54625952/how-to-pass-base64-image-string-from-flask-python-code-to-html)

Hope this works. Keep learning.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your suggestion. I tried it out, but I'm facing an error...and I'm not really sure what went wrong here. This is the updates code that I have right now. New edits 1.import base64 2.row=cursor.fetchone(),if row not None loop <-- these edits are in the Image function. 3. In the display function, image_data = Image(data["search"]), encoded_image=base64.base64encode(image_data).decode("UTF-8) 4. In the render template, encoded_image=encoded_image 5. in the html, <img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ image_data }}" alt="image">. Im getting a TypeError for the encoded_image line

Comment: it says : type error: a bytes like object is required, not NoneType.

Comment: Hi, so it's going inside the else block of the code. make sure your query returns a result.